# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(roleName) always returns false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on adding authorization to an ASP.NET MVC App and have run into a road block.  I was finally able to get our custom membership provider wired up and get authentication working for the App. Now, as expected, if I add the [Authorize] attribute to my controllers, the user must be authenticated to view the page. I have also successfully tested [Authorize(Users="{userName}")] which also works to restrict the page to that specific user.

The problem is that [Authorize(Roles="{RoleName}")] does not seem to work as I'm expecting. If I add that attribute to a controller, anytime I try to access the corresponding page, I am redirected to our login page. This is what I would expect to have happen if the user does not have the required role, but it is happening even if the user has that role.  I have checked both User.IsInRole("{roleName}") and HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("{roleName}") in a View, a Controller and a Helper method and this always returns 'False'.

I have verified that the users I am working with have the roles I am trying to authorize against. I have also tested these users in a WebForms App that restricts page access by the same roles and it works fine. I figure that I have something setup wrong somewhere or am missing something simple, but after searching all morning, I haven't found anything that has gotten me any closer to the solution, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

Comment: Hey, you could edit your answer to tell us what the configs were - might help others in the future.

Comment: sirrocco - the config settings were specific to our implementation and environment so they wouldn't be of any use to anyone else.

Comment: Your comment prompted me to double-check my web.config and I discovered that the roleManager node had enabled="false".  I just wanted people to know that if it's disabled it returns false for IsInRole as opposed to returning an exception of some sort like you might expect.

Comment: Did you try to add WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(..) ?

Answer (score 4):

First : use a profiler and when executing the HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("{roleName}")  line, check what the sql query is.

If it's not making a query then you probably have cacheRolesInCookie="true" and IsInRole will be checking the FormsAuthenticationTicket for UserData. Be sure that when you create the FormsAuthenticationTicket you set the userdata parameter to a comma delimited string with the roles of the user.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't solve the problem, but it did lead me down a road that eventually did.  It turns out that there were some extra config settings that are needed to get out role provider fully working that no one bothered to tell me about.  Once I stumbled upon those, everything 'magically' started to work.

Comment: what was that, i have the same problem, can you kindly let me know

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem as the OP.  Although this is an old post, I thought I would put what worked for me.  What I found was that the role provider was disabled in the web.config. I set enabled to true and it solved my issue.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="myRoleProvider">
```

Comment: Yup, lol, that did it. All these complicated solutions and it turn out to be a simple switch. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case others find this question:

I encountered a similar issue and the problem was spaces in the domain group.  Using whatever `HttpContext.Current.User` returns, calls to `IsInRole()` seems to compare using the pre-Windows 2000 group name which doesn't contain spaces.

In my case stripping the spaces from the group name passed to `IsInRole()` fixed the issue.

Here's a nifty extension method to do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes all spaces from a string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The string</param>
/// <returns>The string without spaces</returns>
public static string StripSpaces(this string value)
{
    // my test using both long and short strings showed StringBuilder 
    // to be slightly faster at this than string.Replace()

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(value);

    b.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

    return b.ToString();
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal` and call `IsMemberOf()` which should work better with domain groups that contain spaces.

- [msdn - WindowsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sh5x3s59.aspx)
- [msdn - UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an old topic, but I had a similar problem and the cause was in:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(string, bool)
```

I was using the user's identity token (Guid) as first parameter, since the code I was working with used a variable named `token`, but in reality it must be a valid username.  I found this out after using the profiler and running the aspnetdb's stored proc manually.  The MSDN doc also confirms this.

It also causes `[Authorize(Roles="rolename")]` to fail, even if the user is in the role, though `[Authorize]` works.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing out your browser cookie cache. I spent a while banging my head on a similar problem, and clearing out my cookies solved the problem.